# Adding data information into the layers

Tags: qgis, excel

As total newbie of QGIS, I am slowly progressing into using properly QGIS but I lack of knowledge of the software.

I am missing the knowledge to edit .shp files in the goal of adding or changing data.

Context: I have a shape layer already being done and I would like to add data in each specific areas so I can fetch later the information of the area with the 'Identity features' tool.

Finally, last question is there an efficient way to drop the data from an Excel file (.xls) to the QGIS shape layer(s) ? The context would be that I have some updated data and after making a new Excel with all of the updated data for each parcel I would drop them into the QGIS to update the map so I can simply click on the desired zone with the 'Identity features' tool to have the needed data.

This is an example of a selected area of the shape layer

[image: This is an example of a selected area of the shape layer]

And this is the tab I would like to be able to edit

[image: And this is the tab I would like to be able to edit]

I added some pictures to make sure my rambling is more clear because I was using QGIS in French before so some terms might be different (or poorly translated by myself).

I've been also trying to follow guides on the matter but it's a bit complicated with the mix of outdated ones and the up to date.

Comment: What questions on the issue of changing attributes does the [official tutorial leave open](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/index.html)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are a problem-solving site. We're not here for primary instruction or tutorial fabrication. Questions should state what you have tried and what problem you encountered.